# ElasticSearch.Net - Remove index in a bulk query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I'm implementing a reindexing operation, which takes all of the elements from a certain set and adds them into the index, replacing the old content of the index (or created index if it's empty). To achieve that I use the Elasticsearch bulk query, which I call with Elasticsearch.net Bulk function.

I've succeeded in adding elements to the index/creating new index with all of the elements, but I can't seem to find out how to delete the whole index in a bulk query, in order to ensure that there are no old content items left in it. I could do it with another call, but this means that if I delete the index and then there's a failure in recreating it, I am left with no index, while I guess, in a bulk query if there was a failure the index wouldn't be deleted.

This is what I have for bulk indexing right now (and it works):

```
foreach (var element in elements)
{
   sb.AppendLine("{ \"index\" : { \"_id\" : \"" + element.Id + "\" } }");
   sb.AppendLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element.As<ElementDTO>(), new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None }));                        
}

var response = client.Bulk("elements", "element", sb.ToString());
```

I've tried adding:

```
sb.AppendLine("{ \"delete\" : { \"_index\" : \"elements\" } }");
```

or:

```
sb.AppendLine("{ \"delete\" }");
```

before the foreach but to no avail. Is there a way do delete the index in a bulk before adding elements to it?

Comment: Can't you just delete and create index before bulk operation?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'd like to have it in a bulk, so that if any element of reindexing fails, I still have the old index unharmed, rather than nothing. At least I suppose it would work that way.

Comment: so I think [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) method should help you.

Comment: Hear hear @Rob. Aliases are the way forward for this particular scenario!

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, going to go in that direction then.